# unordered list with anchor tags in Angular not opening dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am having issues with my dropdown with Angular. It wants to navigate to the link instead of opening the drop down.
Just putting '#' didn't work so I tried forcing it by getting the current URL and supplying that with the '#' appended to the end to emulate it, but that didn't work either. (I know very little of angular) So then I removed the href altogether and now it's clickable without navigation, but it doesn't open the drop down. I have no idea what to do...

I've tried several options I have found on here and all over the internet, but I can't seem to get anything to work.

here is my ts file

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private navService: NavigationService, private location: Location) { }



  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.currentUrl = this.location.path() + "#"
    this.navService.getLogoLink()
      .subscribe(link => {
        this.logoHref = link
      })
  }

  @Input() user?: CurrentUser
  @Output() onLogOut = new EventEmitter()
  @Output() onGoToProfile = new EventEmitter()
  logoHref = ""
  currentUrl = ""

  goToProfile() {
    this.onGoToProfile.emit("onGoToProfile")
  }

  logOut() {
    this.onLogOut.emit("onLogOut")
  }

}
```

and here is my HTML

```
<a href="{{currentUrl}}" data-dropdown="drop-not-bar" class="notif-drop-down"><span class="hide">Account Options Menu</span><span class="arrow"></span></a>
            <ul id="drop-not-bar" class="notif-drop-down-menu" data-dropdown-content>
              <li><a id="profile-link" (click)="goToProfile()">Account</a></li>
              <li><a id="logout-link" (click)="logOut()">Log Out</a></li>
            </ul>
```

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> It wants to navigate to the link instead of opening the drop down.

That is because you are using anchor tag using `div` instead should solve the issue.